# Sending Soap with attachment with Mule ESB

Tags: httpclient, mule, axis, multipartform-data, multipart

I am using Mule ESB version 1.3 and as soap engine it has AXIS1.4 embedded.Mule uses the code below to send stream as ws attachment. I checked they are still using it in newer versions.

```
                File temp = File.createTempFile("soap", ".tmp");
            temp.deleteOnExit(); // TODO cleanup files earlier (IOUtils
                                    // has a file tracker)
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(temp);
            msgContext.getRequestMessage().writeTo(fos);
            fos.close();
            contentLength = (int)temp.length();
            payload = new FileInputStream(temp);
```

Here the content of soap message with attachment is saved on a file and handle for this file is given to the rest of system. I did not get the logic behind this. Why not just use

> javax.activation.DataHandler

inputstream and instead first saving and then reading message from file. As far as I understand Axis1.4 itself not working that way. Am I missing something here ?

After some modifications to make mule send file I came accross the below difference between axis and mule client generated messages. Except this line generated messages are same.
Mule generate this header:

> Content-Type: multipart/related;type="application/xop+xml"

Axis generate this header which is correct:

> Content-Type: multipart/related;type="application/xop+xml"; start="<2F4952A019F62AB6704A0C06DB5E8AA1>"; start-info="text/xml; charset=utf-8"; .boundary="----=_Part_0_1836994030.1387284330292"

What is causing this difference ?

Comment: Mule 1.3 really? It's like 8 years old!

Comment: yeah really, its not my choice but i need to use it.

Comment: Got it, I wanted to be sure as some people confuse Studio and Mule versions. Thanks for confirming it's good old Mule :)